# Insufficient privileges error when trying to add some components to an outbound change set

Tags: error, insufficient-privileges

I'm getting the insufficient privileges error when I'm trying to add Page Layout and Lightning Page components to an outbound change set even though **my account has the System Administrator profile**.

Note: I've tried with other System Administrator accounts, and even with the very first System Administrator account and keep getting the same error.

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this ?